# Installing maven generated artifacts without using the artifactId

Tags: maven

I have a maven parent project with 2 modules. When building the parent project, I want to generate and install the final artifact with a different name than the artifactId used in the pom.xml. I can see that the artifact generated does have the name that I want use in the build dir. However when the archive is installed in the local Maven repository, the maven-install-plugin copies the artifacts using the project's artifactId. How can I configure the plugin to install the artifacts without using the artifactId?

My child project's pom.xml:

```
<project>
   <parent>
      <groupId>com.mycomp</groupId>
      <artifactId>com-mycomp</artifactId>   
      <version>12.0.0.0.0</version>
   </parent>

   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.mycomp</groupId>
   <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
   <version>12.0.0.0.0</version>

   <build>
      <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
      <finalName>${parent.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
      <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies/</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assembly:package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                                <descriptors>
                  <descriptor>src/main/resources/dependencies.xml</descriptor>
                                </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>3.1.2</version>
                           <configuration>
                               <archive>
                                   <manifest>
                                       <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                                       <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                       <mainClass>com.my.MainClass</mainClass>
                                   </manifest>
                               </archive>
                           </configuration>
                       </plugin>

      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

The parent pom.xml:

```
<project>
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.mycomp</groupId>
   <artifactId>com-mycomp</artifactId>   
   <version>12.0.0.0.0</version>
   <packaging>pom</packaging>

   <modules>
     <module>child1</module>
     <module>child2</module>
   </modules>
   :
   :
</project>
```

The desired output of mvn clean install: 
1) com-mycomp-12.0.0.0.0.jar in the local maven repository
2) com-mycomp-12.0.0.0.0.zip comprising of the above jar and its dependencies.

The observed behavior: 
3) com-mycomp-12.0.0.0.0.jar is created in the build dir. But it is installed in the maven repository as child1-12.0.0.0.0.jar
4) com-mycomp-12.0.0.0.0.zip is created in the build dir. But it is installed in the maven repository as child1-12.0.0.0.0.zip

How can I achieve the desired behavior (#1 and #2) ?

Answer (score 0):

Artifacts in the local repository are always installed with their artifactId.

You cannot change that. And even if you could, I would strongly recommend against that because you are breaking expectations.

If you want to create an additional zip that contains the jar with dependencies, you don't need a second module. You can create it through the assembly plugin and attach it with a classifier like `dependencies`. You then have two artifacts like

```
com-mycomp-12.0.0.0.0.jar
com-mycomp-12.0.0.0.0-dependencies.zip
```